# Dodgy - Redundant nullcheck of value known to be null

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-analysis, findbugs

Below is the code where i am getting the Sonar violation

```
public static Connection getConnection(
        String db)
        throws SQLException {

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            Driver dbRriver = (Driver) Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("user", PropertyLoader.get("user123"));
            props.put("password", PropertyLoader.get("pass"));
            connection = dbRriver
                    .connect(PropertyLoader.get("URL"), props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            **if(connection!= null){
            connection.close();**
            }
            LOGGER.error(IN_EXCEPTION, e);
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

the connection needs to be checked for null condition before closing it,but the sonar is giving the violation as "Dodgy - Redundant nullcheck of value known to be null". Please suggest me as how i can avoid this violation without removing the null check.

Comment: your close should not be in your catch, but in your finally statement.

Comment: @Stultuske Normally, yes. But this method is supposed to return an open connection. It doesn't use the connection itself.

Comment: @Stultuske : David is right .i need to return an open connection,so i cannot put the connection.close() in finally block.

Answer (score 2):

Because either way, if you end up in `catch`, `connection` will always be null. There are several places where you can have an exception, but all they are before you assignment `connection = dbRriver.connect(PropertyLoader.get("URL"), props);`
So it will always be null in `catch`. 
Yes, you need to put this code in `finally` as @Stultuske suggests

Comment: But if i put the code in finally block, i will always end up sending a closed connection.But my requirement is to send an open connection.

Answer (score 2):

As it's already mentioned, you cannot end up in `catch (Exception ex)` clause with non-null `connection`. Seems that this check is absolutely redundant and you can remove it.

Also note that your method is declared as throwing `SQLException`, but it's actually never thrown. In case of Exception the caller will receive the `null` value. Seems to be bad practice: what caller should do with this `null`? To my opinion the whole try-catch is useless. Just let the exception propagate to the caller. Well, you may leave the `catch` block, but wrap the original `Exception` into `SQLException` instead:

```
public static Connection getConnection(
    String db) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Driver dbRriver = (Driver) Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", PropertyLoader.get("user123"));
        props.put("password", PropertyLoader.get("pass"));
        return dbRriver.connect(PropertyLoader.get("URL"), props);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SQLException(e);
    }
}
```

Finally note that your `db` parameter is not used.